# Error with C++ function in package with Rcpp appears only on Windows machine

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I've been working on [this package for R](https://github.com/Ward9250/HybRIDS/tree/devel) that I want to use Rcpp with and on the devel branch I've introduced some Rcpp code in the form of one function:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <string>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
LogicalVector sequenceChecker(CharacterMatrix x){
  int nc = x.ncol();
  std::string nss(x.nrow(), 'n');
  std::string Nss(x.nrow(), 'N');
  CharacterVector ns = wrap(nss);
  CharacterVector Ns = wrap(Nss);
  LogicalVector out(nc);
  for(int i=0; i < nc; i++){
    out[i] = is_false(any(x(_,i) == Ns)) && is_false(any(x(_,i) == ns)) && unique(x(_,i)).size() != 1;
  }
  return out;
}
```

I set the project up to use Rcpp with Rstudio so I have the appropriate Imports and Linking to lines in my DESCRIPTION file.

There is also an appropriate `useDynLib` line in the namespace file.

Rcpp generates these two export files:

RcppExports.cpp:

```
// This file was generated by Rcpp::compileAttributes
// Generator token: 10BE3573-1514-4C36-9D1C-5A225CD40393

#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// sequenceChecker_cpp
LogicalVector sequenceChecker_cpp(CharacterMatrix x);
RcppExport SEXP HybRIDS_sequenceChecker_cpp(SEXP xSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    SEXP __sexp_result;
    {
        Rcpp::RNGScope __rngScope;
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< CharacterMatrix >::type x(xSEXP );
        LogicalVector __result = sequenceChecker_cpp(x);
        PROTECT(__sexp_result = Rcpp::wrap(__result));
    }
    UNPROTECT(1);
    return __sexp_result;
END_RCPP
}
```

RcppExports.R:

```
# This file was generated by Rcpp::compileAttributes
# Generator token: 10BE3573-1514-4C36-9D1C-5A225CD40393

sequenceChecker_cpp <- function(x) {
    .Call('HybRIDS_sequenceChecker_cpp', PACKAGE = 'HybRIDS', x)
}
```

On Windows, Mac and Ubuntu it appears to build, and install the package, but when it comes to the point in using the package, when the cpp function is called, it generates an error for Windows, but not the other two systems:

> Error in sequenceChecker_cpp(FullSequence) : 
>         STRING_ELT() can only be applied to a 'character vector', not a 'NULL'

The function is supposed to accept a character matrix and return and logical vector.

I don't understand why it would think it was `NULL` on a Windows box yet work perfectly on my other systems.

I have broken down the C++ code line by line and tested it, and the error seems to occur in this line:

```
out[i] = is_false(any(x(_,i) == Ns)) && is_false(any(x(_,i) == ns)) && unique(x(_,i)).size() != 1;
```

Specifically when `unique` is used: `unique(x(_, i));`

I tested whether the problem was that Rcpp was not working on my Windows machine at all by making a brand new Rcpp skeleton package in Rstudio, containing the `rcpp_hello_world()` and it works perfectly.

I have the latest R and Rtools on the Windows box and have tried several Windows machines, but I've reached the limit of my understanding as I use OS X and Ubuntu almost all the time and have never had an issue using Rcpp on them.

Comment: You could approach this differently, and just work out a C++ solution using std::string and unique() and find() [ to see if mathches occur ]. That way you'd instantiate a string out of row i of you matrix, and you would get by with minimal copying -- and hence minimal source of error.  I'm currently traveling so I can't supply more detail now ...

Comment: I see so each row could be made into a string to find the N's, would I have to make strings for every column of the matrix to find columns containing only one character?

Comment: Hm, columns of chars is harder. I missed that requirement in my first read of this.

Comment: Can you recode the CharacterMatrix as a matrix of integers?  I have no domain knowledge here, but this _must be_ a well-studied problem ...

Comment: I could recode the matrix of characters as one of integers, either 0 to 3 or 1 to 4.

Comment: That may be worth a try.